# Can you leash the Ender Dragon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can you use a leash to tie the Ender Dragon in Minecraft? If you can, will she stay close to the ground or will she fly? If she flies, will the rope just stretch or will you fly along with the Dragon?

Comment: As a side note, the [Ender dragon is female](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Ender_Dragon#Notch-related).

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I forgot that the Dragon drops an egg lol

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Leads are item used to leash and lead **passive and neutral** animals, golems and some monsters.

According to [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lead#Leashing_mobs), it's possible to leash common animals and also the following mobs:

- Chicken Jockey (only the mount)
- Hoglin
- Iron Golem
- Skeleton Horse
- Skeleton Horseman (only the mount)
- Snow Golem
- Strider
- Zoglin
- Zombie Horse

So no, you can't leash the Ender Dragon.
Also because I've found [this suggestion](https://www.reddit.com/r/minecraftsuggestions/comments/8ftonw/you_can_put_leads_on_the_ender_dragon_but_she/) asking the possibility to add that.

Comment: I'm not sure that some random Reddit post is really a good source for this. That said, this is tagged java edition, so what happens if you set the Ender Dragon to be a passive mob and try to leash it, or just directly edit its mob information to allow it to be leashed?

Comment: @nick012000 That's not "a good source", I was just supporting my statement. I don't have Java edition so I can't try that, by the way changing EnderDragon's data with commands or whatever is not what OP is asking imho, so feel free to investigate and post your findings.